# Can I make minor typographical corrections to a title in citations?

Tags: punctuation, dashes, citation

Let's say I need to cite a website or printed report with the title:

> Broccoli production in Ruritania, 1990-2010

with a hyphen in "1990-2010." In English typography, though, the standard indicator for numerical ranges is an [en-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) (–), not the shorter hyphen (-).

Is it licit to substitute an en-dash for a hyphen in a citation or footnote, as in

> See "Broccoli production in Ruritania, 1990–2010," Ruritanian Ministry of Agriculture, 2011.

without remarking on the correction? Strictly speaking, I'm changing the "official" title of the work, but the change is minimal and unlikely to keep anyone from finding the cited work.

Comment: Whatever next? Suppose a cited source used an **"unmatched pair"** of quote marks rather than a **“matched pair”**? Would you tell your typesetter to retain the original? Would you tell him to add **[sic]** to call attention to the (faithfully-reproduced) "error"?

Comment: Question probably belongs more on academia SE, where it has already been discussed: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55525/how-to-refer-to-a-source-with-typos-in-the-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Chicago Manual of Style, 17th Ed., Section 13.7, it is perfectly acceptable to change hyphens to en or em dashes as necessary without the need to remark on the change.